# ReactJS | Getting form values without maintaining states or using getElementByID / refs

Tags: forms, reactjs

I'm new and looking for some optimised way of getting form values

The one that i am using is like this, here is one of my form input -

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onNameChange} />
```

and Its onChange() function is -

```
onNameChange: function(e){
  this.setState({
    name: e.target.value
  })
}
```

I have to pass this form value to parent component using a callBack function, that will take the state as its value, than these values are going to be the states for the parent..
Also I'm not looking to use any refs or Id assign to  tags because i will have several forms later on

Is there is any efficient way to get form values without using states ..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only other proper way to get the form field value in react besides an on change handler is using a ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [form-serialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-serialize) on the form's onSubmit action after seeing Ryan Florence mention it on twitter (I don't know if he uses it or recommends it, just trying to show I didn't invent it):

```
onFormSubmit: function (event) {
    let formData = serializeForm(event.target, { hash: true });
    // formData = { foo: 'bar' } 
}

render: function () {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar"/>
            <input type="submit" value="do it!"/>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Taken from http://myappincome.co.uk/using-form-serialize-in-react-js-forms/

Comment: hi @MattDuFeu, thanks for this reply, so far this has been the most helpful and interesting answer as it made me aware of a new npm package,  I am actually having multiple forms at same page and i am working on implementing it, if you have any useful link for dealing with multiple forms in optimized way please share its URL..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use react link state mixins

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

```
var LinkedStateMixin = require('react-addons-linked-state-mixin');

var WithLink = React.createClass({
  mixins: [LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {message: 'Hello!'};
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" valueLink={this.linkState('message')} />;
  }
});
```

Your message text field will be linked to state message